# fullPage.js - scroll back to the top do not work

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js jQuery Plugin with `scrollOverflow: true`. When I scroll down and want to return back to the top of the page it does not work in mobile devices.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({       
    paddingTop: '50px',
    paddingBottom: '50px',
    scrollOverflow: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

scrollOverflow acts as a normal `overflow:scroll` element. It is not suppose to go back to the top as you can see in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).